# How to get category lists by name or slug

Tags: theme-development, categories

Currently I am able to get all categories but I want only few categories to display based on name or slug for example.

```
$categories = get_categories('accessibility','wcag', 'abc');
```

is this possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by "few categories to display"? Do you want posts from those categories, or just the term objects themselves?

Comment: just term objects

Comment: What criteria? You need to be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for specific term objects from the term slugs, from a specific taxonomy, I think [new WP_Term_Query()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Term_Query/__construct/) is your best bet:

```
$term_args = array(
  'taxonomy' => 'category',
  'name' => array( 'accessibility','wcag', 'abc' )
  'hide_empty' => false,
  'fields' => 'all',
  'count' => true,
);

$term_query = new WP_Term_Query($term_args);

foreach($term_query->terms as $term){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($term); // You'll see the term object here, which is what I think you are after
    echo '</pre>';
}
```